# Integrate the following : $\int_{a}^{b}{\sqrt{{{a}^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}\left( x \right)+{{b}^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\left( x \right)}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate

$$\int_a^b\sqrt{a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x}\,dx$$

So far I have gotten:

$$ \int_a^b \sqrt{a^2+(b^2-a^2)\cos^2x}\,dx $$

I was the told to make a substituion for $\cos x$ to deal with it.

I have tried many common identities like half angle and $u$ substitution like $u = \cos(x)$ ... etc

Note sorry for poor format this is my first ever post.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've gotten you started on fixing the MathJax formatting.  Take a look at what I've done if you're having trouble figuring out the commands.

Comment: This type of integral is an Elliptic Integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral, where you have something of the form $\sqrt{C+\cos^2 x}$ or $\sqrt{C+\sin^2 x}$ as your integrand. I'm pretty sure that your integral is incalculable because of this. $$$$ Otherwise, my first step would be to pull $a^2$ out of the root to get $a \cdot \int \sqrt{1+C\cdot\cos^2x}\ dx$, where $C=(b^2-a^2)/a^2)$.

Answer (score 5):

The antiderivative is not an elementary function. The limits $a$ and $b$ are not nice points. This is an [incomplete elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind), and there is no explicit elementary formula for the answer.